# compilation error when including directory containing headers

Tags: c++

I have a directory `maths` which is a library that is comprised solely of header files.
I am trying to compile my program by running the following command in my home directory:

```
g++ -I ../maths prog1.cpp prog2.cpp test.cpp -o et -lboost_date_time -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

but I get the following compilation error:

```
prog1.cpp:4:23: fatal error: maths/Dense: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
prog2.cpp:6:23: fatal error: maths/Dense: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

`maths` is located in the same directory(i.e. my home directory) as the .cpp files and I am running the compilation line from my home as well.

prog1.cpp and prog2.cpp have the following headers
`#include<maths/Dense>` on lines 4 and 6 respectively, hence I am getting the error.

how do I fix it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not Dense.h or Dense.hpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maths is located in the same directory(i.e. my home directory) as the .cpp files

Your include path is given as `-I ../maths`. You need `-I ./maths` – or simpler, `-I maths` since `maths` is a subdirectory *of the current directory*, not of the parent directory. Right?

Then in your C++ file, use `#include <Dense>`. If you want to use `#include <maths/Dense>` you need to adapt the include path. However, using `-I.` may lead to massive problems<sup>1</sup>, I strongly advise *against* this.

Instead, it’s common practice to have an `include` subdirectory that is included. So your folder structure should preferably look as follows:

```
./
+ include/
| + maths/
|   + Dense
|
+ your_file.cpp
```

Then use `-I include`, and in your C++ file, `#include <maths/Dense>`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Consider what happens if you’ve got a file `./map.cpp` from which you generate an executable called `./map`. As soon as you use `#include <map>` anywhere in your code, this will try to include `./map` instead of the `map` standard header.

Answer (score 2):

You can either change your include path to `-I..` or your includes to `#include <Dense>`

Wait, if `maths` is in the same directory as your source files and that is your current directory, you can either change your include path to `-I.` or your includes to `#include "Dense"`